# grand total with the count times and the numeric

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to add grand total for all the three columns for the query below. The second and third column are numeric, so it is easily  to give them grand total. However, I also want to add total at the first column: add up the number of computer ID.
Is there any to do so?
Thanks!!

```
  SQL> select comp_id, count(loan_id) "num_computer", count(st_id) "st_num"
      2  from computer left join loan using (comp_id)
      3    left join student using (st_id)
      4  group by grouping sets ((),comp_id)
      5  ;

COMP_ num_computer     st_num
----- ------------ ----------
1001             2          2
1002             0          0
1003             2          2
1004             0          0
1005             0          0
1006             1          1
1007             3          3
1008             1          1
1009             0          0
1010             1          1
                10         10
```

Comment: Hey mister, if you need help I recommend you to provide us some test data and describe the table result what you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to add another column:

```
select comp_id, sum(1) as cnt, count(loan_id) "num_computer", count(st_id) "st_num"
from computer left join
     loan
     using (comp_id) left join
     student
     using (st_id)
group by grouping sets ((comp_id), ());
```

You can fiddle with `case` to get the two values in a single column, but this is awkward because one is a string and the other a number.

Comment: Hello, What is sum(1) means? Actually, I want to count the total number of comp_id, which is 10. Thanks!!

Comment: @吳芯緰 . . . You could actually use `count(*)` as well.  When I wrote it, I was thinking "put `1` there", but that doesn't work because you need to add them up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select   
  CASE
      WHEN GROUPING(comp_id) = 1 THEN count(comp_id) ELSE comp_id END  comp_id, 
  count(loan_id) "num_computer", 
  count(st_id) "st_num"
from computer left join loan using (comp_id)
left join student using (st_id)
group by grouping sets ((comp_id), ());
```